Context managers as attributes
I am having a hard time to write clean code with context managers in Python without getting in a context manager hell. Imagine something like:
class A:
  def __init__(self):
     self.b =  B()  # where B is a context manager

This leaks now, because I did not use a with statement. In the wild I have seen two solutions to this:

Inject B in the class and have some outer with statement
with B() as b: 
   a = A(b)


Make A a context manager as well that implements closing B:
with A() as a:
   ...
# A will close B now in its __exit__ method



I dislike both methods. In my example the usage of B inside of A is an implementation detail. It is not something I want to expose to the outer world. Thus, Option 1 is obviously not suitable, but even Option 2 exposes some details. Mainly that A does some resource management. Additionally having to manually implement the __exit__ method does seem to defeat a little bit the purpose of B being a context manager, if I cannot use the context manager syntax.
So I am sort of missing the C++ RAII here I think, which is not directly suitable for Python. So how can I avoid making basically all my classes context managers if there is a dependency chain?
To give a very concrete use case:
An ML agent (like ChatGPT) wants to execute code. So I might have a class Agent that can execute code. This is done with jupyter notebook. Thus my program needs a jupyter notebook server running. Ideally I would like to encapsulate this within the Agent class. The Agent class starts the server and stops the server. The server here is implemented as a context manager. The solution I would come up with is making the Agent now a context manager too, which I dislike. Because then some class using the Agent needs to become a context manager too, ...  so in the end my whole program is a context manager.

Providing a context manager interface doesn't mean you can't still provide a conventional one in addition. Look at how file can be either closed explicitly or used as a context manager and closed on leaving scope. Nothing stops you from doing the same in your own code; just have __exit__ call a method that also has its own direct means of invocation. Similarly, if you really want more automatic lifecycle management, __del__ exists (though mind the caveats).

This is hard/impossible to answer without knowing the lifetimes of the involved objects. Is you "server" a long lived object that exists for the whole duration of the program? Or is it very short lived such that you could open the server once for each request? Or something in between? What i like to do is: have an interface for A that does not depend on B and an implementation of A that does use B. Then in you composition root use context managers to open all resources, construct objects using the open resources and finally run your program

(__del__ might look and feel more like RAII, but with is far closer to the important parts of RAII's behavior - specifically, ensuring that the cleanup happens when it's actually supposed to.)

@CharlesDuffy   But it does not really fix it, right? Instead of using with A() as the caller now needs to call a.close() or something like that. But then again the fact that A does some ressource management is not really hidden. I suppose del is one option, but not sure if that is the python way of doing things.

"Because then some class using the Agent needs to become a context manager too, ... so in the end my whole program is a context manager." - do you actually have extremely deep ownership chains in your real code? In practice, I think this rarely goes higher than 2 or 3 levels.

@Wombatz Something in between I suppose. I descirbed the use case in the end. So in my case it is an Jupyter Server. Not something you would want to spin up for every single request. Whether you do it once for the whole program or perhaps for a single data point in the dataset (which is a longer interaction, but not the whole program) is a design choice I guess. Assume the latter here.

@user2357112 In my concrete use case not too much. Although I feel like 3 levels is already annoying in this case. As described, I do not even like one level. Because if the ressource is internally, then this should be encapsulated. By making the outer class a context manager (or using explicit close / stop / ... functions) it feels like I am leaking implementation details.

@Wombatz Would you mind creating an answer with a more detailed example. I am not sure I can follow your thought here. If say factory create_A uses a with statement inside to create B and I return from this my A, then B would be destructed, no? I think I could technically yield inside from a with statement, but I think I saw a SO post that this is not really exception safe and defeats sort of the purpose. But maybe I do not fully understand your idea, right now.

Sorry, i deleted that comment, because the idea does not work

It doesn't "really" fix it, but it's good enough. This is how people have been writing Python in practice for decades.

All this leaves me wondering why you expect context manager behavior to be triggered when you don't use its scoping mechanism - i.e. with.  Sure, you may have to do something else to achieve what you want with a simple, no-with, assignment.  And you may even get to complain about __del__ guarantees, or lack thereof.  But context managers are predicated on with and it seems pointless to "argue with the compiler" as you are doing here.  Notably, you could always call __exit__ yourself in your code.  This isn't to say context managers are perfect, just be realistic about their use.

@JLPeyret I try to figure out what the python way is of solving such a problem. Because from my C++ perspective it feels like I am doing something wrong. If the pythonic solution is to actually convert classes that need context managers to context managers too, then so be it. I just assumed that I was maybe missing some feature, maybe some way to directly use with statements for class members. So I expect either an answer with 1. You solve it with Option 3 ... 2. You solutions are correct and yes they are shitty 3. Your solutions are correct and they are good because ...

This question is likely to be answered by opinions. Anyway, here's my opinion. Why not expose the resource heavy nature of the implementation of A, by renaming A as AUsingB?
